# Target elements with different ids Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I target a particular element used with different ids.For instance  that have the ids row and col. I have tried doing this with jquery.

```
var $drag = $( "#col" );
var $drag2 = $( "#row" );
$("td", $drag, $drag2).droppable({ accept: ".special" });
```

But the second id "row" stored in drag2 is not selected. What is the proper way of doing this in jquery.

Comment: If you're using IDs more than once consider using a CLASS name instead. IDs should always be unique.

Comment: they are are unique IDs with similar elements in them

Comment: Answer given will do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$( "#col, #row" ).find("td")
```

or

```
var $drag = $( "#col" );
var $drag2 = $( "#row" );
$drag.add($drag2).find("td").droppable({ accept: ".special" });
```

Comment: is there any reason why you didn't use the variables drag and drag2 in your first answer?

Comment: @lboyel first answer takes selectors are argument, `drag` and `drag2` are not selectors

Comment: so a variable is not considered a selector even thought it has a selector stored within it?

Comment: @lboyel no... in this case the variable is not referring a selector.. it is referring a jQuery wrapper object.. if the variable was like `var selector = '#col, #row'` then we could have used it